# `static_assert` and order or errors in constructor

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++17, static-assert

Why does this `static_assert` in the body trip earlier than the error I’m checking for which occurs before that in the code?  And is this standard behavior, or compiler specific?

I was surprised to find that this works as I wanted to achieve:

```
template<typename R, typename>
Fizzer_t::Fizzer_t (const R & range_of_itemdefs)
    : playdef { std::begin(range_of_itemdefs), std::end(range_of_itemdefs) }
{
    static_assert (std::is_constructible_v<itemdef_t, typename boost::range_value<R>::type>);
}
```

The `static_assert` is in the body of the constructor, which is both lexically and flow-wise *after* the initialization of the members where the the same condition causes a real error.

I thought I would need to puzzle out another level of indirection to get a clean `static_assert`, rather than getting the spew of details from the template expansions of the member’s constructor call.

The only thing I could find in n4659 is §10 ¶6 on page 156.  It just says that this causes an (intentional) error; nothing about what phase it’s found in or what order the parts of a function are analysed in.

Comment: I am not that sure, but are you sure that you did not forget something in the std::is_constructible_v for the second arguments? I never seen typename used like that. maybe you forget a ::type after range_value<R>

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Could you add more context? or an MVCE that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @AntoineMorrier yes, I forgot the `::type`.  As posted originally, it still showed the behavior, but would not succeed on a correct type.

Comment: ```static_assert``` is compile time error. Please provide a [mcve] and generated errors.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk I **know** it is a compile-time error!  IAC, G.Giordano had no trouble understanding what I was asking and already posted an answer.

Comment: That's very good, that somebody understands the question. But to give a good answer I like to refer to concrete situations/examples.

Answer (score 4):

The c++ standard does not guarantee that compiler error messages are issued in a specific order, either lexical or flow-wise. 
This is a recurring behavior, especially in case of multiple errors. Furthermore, you could not be notified of all the errors in your code, but just a few of them, as compiling process is interrupted when it reaches a critical error.